# How to Optimize nested SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below SQL that needs to be optimized (the name of "properties" has been changed to more generic in the below code):

It is running in Azure SQL

```
SELECT ContactValueA, ContactValueB, SUM(X.Price) as Price, SUM(X.ValueX) AS ValueX, SUM(X.ValueY) AS ValueY, Count (*) As [Count]
FROM
    (
        SELECT OL.id, O.ContactValueA, O.ContactValueB,
        OL.Price,
        OL.ValueX,
        OL.ValueY
        FROM [OrderLines] AS OL
        JOIN [Orders] AS O
        ON OL.OrderId = O.Id
        WHERE O.Id in 
            (
                SELECT MIN(SO.Id) AS OID
                FROM [Orders] AS SO
                WHERE SO.[Type] = 'cake'
                AND SO.Created >= @begin  and SO.Created < @end
                AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM [3Orders] AS SOA
                    WHERE SOA.ExtOrderId = SO.ExtOrderId
                    AND SOA.[Type] = 'cake'
                    AND SOA.Created < @begin
                )
                GROUP BY SO.ExtOrderId
            )   
    ) X
GROUP BY X.ContactValueA, X.ContactValueB
```

@begin and @end is both DateTimeOffset

If we look at this part of the code:

```
                SELECT MIN(SO.Id) AS OID
                FROM [Orders] AS SO
                WHERE SO.[Type] = 'cake'
                AND SO.Created >= @begin  and SO.Created < @end
                AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM [3Orders] AS SOA
                    WHERE SOA.ExtOrderId = SO.ExtOrderId
                    AND SOA.[Type] = 'cake'
                    AND SOA.Created < @begin
                )
                GROUP BY SO.ExtOrderId
```

About the orders table - Each order has a unique ID and a not unique ExtOrderId - since an entry in the orders table can be a partial order (partial orders share the same ExtOrderId)

In the above code I need to look at all orders (partial orders) between two datetimeoffsets - and take the partial orders with the lowest ID - But the partial order ID (ExtOrderId) must not have an order before the begin date.

Any suggestions how to optimize this?

Comment: What indexes do you have? Also, can you post an execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` analytic function for getting minimum id

```
with cte as
(

SELECT OL.id, O.ContactValueA, O.ContactValueB,
        OL.Price,
        OL.ValueX,
        OL.ValueY,
        row_number()over(partition by O.type order by o.id) rn
        FROM [OrderLines] AS OL
        JOIN [Orders] AS O
        ON OL.OrderId = O.Id
) ContactValueA, ContactValueB, SUM(Price) as Price, SUM(ValueX) AS ValueX, SUM(ValueY) AS ValueY, Count (*) As [Count] from cte where rn=1
group by ContactValueA, ContactValueB
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a subquery, I would use a left join and return the rows with no previous order found.

your query :

```
        SELECT MIN(SO.Id) AS OID
        FROM [Orders] AS SO
        WHERE SO.[Type] = 'cake'
        AND SO.Created >= @begin  and SO.Created < @end
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [3Orders] AS SOA
            WHERE SOA.ExtOrderId = SO.ExtOrderId
            AND SOA.[Type] = 'cake'
            AND SOA.Created < @begin
        )
        GROUP BY SO.ExtOrderId
```

will be :

```
            SELECT MIN(SO.Id) AS OID
            FROM [Orders] AS SO
                 LEFT JOIN [3Orders] AS SOA ON     SOA.ExtOrderId = SO.ExtOrderId
                                               AND SOA.[Type] = 'cake'
                                               AND SOA.Created < @begin
            WHERE     SO.[Type] = 'cake'
                  AND SO.Created >= @begin  and SO.Created < @end
                  AND SOA.Id IS NULL -- Here we ensure that it has no previous orders
            GROUP BY SO.ExtOrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT MIN(SO.Id) AS OID
    FROM [Orders] AS SO
    WHERE SO.[Type] = 'cake' AND SO.Created < @end
    GROUP BY SO.ExtOrderId 
    HAVING MIN(SO.Created) >= @begin
), T1 AS (
    SELECT OL.id, O.ContactValueA, O.ContactValueB,
        OL.Price,
        OL.ValueX,
        OL.ValueY
    FROM [OrderLines] AS OL
    INNER JOIN T ON T.OID = OL.OrderId
    INNER JOIN [Orders] AS O ON T.OID = O.Id
) SELECT ContactValueA, ContactValueB, SUM(T1.Price) as Price, SUM(T1.ValueX) AS ValueX, SUM(T1.ValueY) AS ValueY, Count (*) As [Count]
FROM T1 
GROUP BY T1.ContactValueA, T1.ContactValueB
```